# Как правильно взять ссылку с русскими буквами?

Tags: java, url

Парсю ссылки из html файла.

Часть адреса на английском, часть русскими буквами, например так:

[http://roga.ru/article/новость/картинка1.jpg](http://roga.ru/article/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B01.jpg)

Когда пытаюсь открыть такую ссылку с помощью данной функции и скачать файл, то получаю просто html'ку http://roga.ru/article/

```
    public HtmlToString(String url) throws Exception {

    URL pageURL = new URL(url);
    URLConnection uc = pageURL.openConnection();

    String codePage = "windows-1251";

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    uc.getInputStream(), codePage));
    try {
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            this.sb.append(inputLine);
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}

    public static void downloadFile(URL url, String filename) {
    try {
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Может кто помочь советом, пожалуйста?

Ну и плюс если выводить такую ссылку в консоль Intellij Idea, то кликабельная часть на английском, а русские буквы просто текстом идут.

Answer (score 1):

В URL допустима только одна кодировка - ASCII см. [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). Для преобразования URL к правильному виду пользуйтесь [java.net.URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) и [java.net.URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)